# How to use Apple Domain IP as Proxy

Tags: firefox, proxy, speed, ip-address, isp

My ISP let me to browse at high speed (20 Mbps) under www.apple.com domain, even though I've reached my maximum quota. This because I subscribed to Apple Music, this is include services like Apps Store and iTunes.

How can I use Apple's IP address as proxy, so I can browse other website like Google or Yahoo at high speed, like under apple domain. Because once my quota reach it's limit, my internet speed get throttled.

I've tried changing Firefox > Manual Proxy and set Apple IP as proxy, but doesn't worked.

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Long answer: You get what you pay for (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain't_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch)

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Rolled back to original question.

Comment: Upvoting question.  I suspect people downvote the question because it seems like an attempt to cheat.  Regardless, the question does show there was some effort to resolve, and the question is clear.  This is also a good topic for people to be aware of when they set up network security.  I recall reading about (historically) having unlimited free (TCP/IP) Internet at any Starbucks using T-Mobile just because DNS was unrestricted.  A more recent [article about bypassing limits](http://bryceboe.com/2012/03/12/bypassing-gogos-inflight-internet-authentication/) discusses such concepts a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.

This would require Apple to supply you with an actual proxy server that you can connect to, but obviously, there would be no reason for them to do that. You can't use an arbitrary IP address as a proxy, as there needs to be a proxy server running on a specific IP address plus corresponding proxy port. If that IP address is not under your control, you have to rely on someone else setting up a proxy on that IP for you.

Just imagine what would happen if this were possible. Everyone using the Internet could "fake" their requests by simply using any other arbitrary IP address. This would allow for many shady things to be done on the back of others who wouldn't even know about it. Would you want someone to use your Internet connection as a proxy, without giving them explicit permission?

Comment: Upvoting, because the criteria (given by the hovertext) is that the answer is useful.  So I'm up-voting, even if the answer isn't correct.  The correct answer is that it requires Apple's cooperation, and there is some possibility that Apple might have a server that could do this.  But once that is sufficiently publicly discovered (like if we pointed it out here), Apple would likely take it down to prevent ongoing abuse.  Therefore, we can't provide a long-term answer that will remain workable.  Whether slhck's answer is *currently* correct or not, this will be correct over the long term.